# why is using a small vocabulary for topic modelling bad?

Tags: scikit-learn, natural-language, topic-models, bag-of-words

i am trying to classify texts into topics. for example, let's say one of the topics is cooperation. so in the [vocab param of the sklearn api](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#:%7E:text=vocabularyMapping%20or%20iterable%2C%20default%3DNone). so some of the prevalent words (or "tokens" are they more correctly called?) might be words like 'group' or 'together'. but some of the words will simply be 'cooperate' and 'cooperating'. so is it naive to simply use a small set of hand picked vocab words. and if so why? my boss is telling me that it will be a solution that will break easily and not be flexible to adapt wel to new data that i have not seen. but i don't understand fully, because my system is performing much better when i use a few hand picked keywords rather than include the less important terms like 'make','time', 'need' which frankly (based on my labeled training data) do not appear to alter the performance at all. so i figure just get rid of them. am i being naive?

Comment: “ my system is performing much better”—can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Are you training by taking texts known to be about cooperation and having the classification algorithm identify the significant vocabulary?  I've been surprised by some correlations between words and topics.

Comment: yes that is what i am doing. i am also sometimes surprised by the voacb that shows as being significant. but for most of my topics, there often only 2-5 keywords that are important, and the others (e.g. make, time, need) just don't help nor hurt the score, so i want to leave them out of the vocab (because in my mind theyare basically stop words). but my manager is trying to kindly explain to me that my solution is fragile and won't adapt well to new unseen text passages.

Comment: Perhaps your manager has some specific ideas? Can you show your approach is "fragile" or "robust" to new texts?  You can only train with the texts you have.  Perhaps a more complicated model using clusters/chains/order of multiple words?